# useQuery hook invoked multiple times by re-render gets executed only once

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am using useQuery hook to fetch data and it gets called multiple times during re-render, but the onSuccess callback gets called only once.

```
export async function postWithoutCancellation({ queryKey, pageParam, responseType }) {
  const url = queryKey[0];
  let body = queryKey[1];
  if (pageParam) {
    body = { ...body, ...pageParam };
  }

  const { data } = await axiosInstance.post(url, body, {
    ...config1,
    responseType,
  });
  return data;
}

const [lazyLoadRowDataQuery, setlazyLoadRowDataQuery] = useState(null);
  const metricDataLazyLoad = useQuery(
    [
      `/api/call`,
      {
        ...filters,
        queries: getQueryMetrics(selectedDimensions, lazyLoadRowDataQuery),
        // ...(view_metrics ? { attributionType: view_metrics } : {}),
      },
    ],
    postWithoutCancellation,
    {
      enabled: !!lazyLoadRowDataQuery,
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        console.log('On success callback', data, lazyLoadRowDataQuery)
      }
    }
  );

useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        console.log('Entries', entries, timeouts.current)

        entries.forEach(e => {
          const rowKey = e?.target?.getAttribute('data-row-key') as string;
          if (e.isIntersecting) {
            const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
              // observer.unobserve(e.target)

              // handling
              const element = paginatedData.find(item => item.key === +rowKey);
              setlazyLoadRowDataQuery(element);
              // metricDataLazyLoad.refetch();
              // metricDataLazyLoad.mutation();

            }, 1000)  // delay for 1 second
            timeouts.current[rowKey] = timerId
          } else {
              clearTimeout(timeouts.current[rowKey])
          }
        })
      }, {
        root: tableRef.current.querySelector('.ant-table-body'),
        threshold: 0
      }
    );
    
    const tableRows = tableRef.current.querySelectorAll('.ant-table-row');
    // observer.observe(tableRows[0]);
    console.log('Table rows', tableRows, tableRef.current.querySelector('.ant-table-tbody'));
    if (Array.from(tableRows).length > 0) {
      Array.from(tableRows).forEach((item: any) => observer.observe(item))
    }

    return () => {
      if (Array.from(tableRows).length > 0) {
        Array.from(tableRows).forEach((item: any) => observer.disconnect(item))
      }
    };
  }, [paginatedData, timeouts]);
```

Suppose, if 5 elements are in view, then callback will be called 5 times, which will trigger setlazyLoadRowDataQuery 5 times and due to this, 5 network calls are made, but the onSuccess callback is called only once, which is for last data. For initial 4 calls, the callback never executes.

I tried using useQueries hook but the state maintenance is little bit complicated

Answer (score 0):

you set the lazyLoadRowDataQuery state multiple times inside the useEffect hook so  which triggers the useQuery hook to fetch data multiple times. As a result the onSuccess callback is only called for the last data fetched.instead of settimeout you used debouncing technique to delay the execution of setlazyLoadRowDataQuery method until a certain amout of time has passed then This will prevent multiple network calls from being made and ensure that the onSuccess callback is called only once

Comment: I actually want multiple API calls which is working fine. But the onSuccess callback is executed only once for that last data which I dont want. If I hit api 5 times, it should trigger onSuccess callback 5 times, which is not happening currently.

Comment: the onSuccess callback is only called for the current observer. It would be even weirder to call it 5 times with stale values in closures. What are you doing in the onSuccess callback? Note that we are about to deprecate it and will remove it in the next major version, see: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/breaking-react-querys-api-on-purpose